# Python insert into %s MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert some data into a database using the variable test as the table name. But unfortunately I cant seem to achieve this. Can anyone help me out?

From my raise I am getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

My code:

```
   test = "hello"
   # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","admin","password","table" )

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO %s (name,
            age, gender)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(test))
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql, (name, age, gender))
        db.commit()
    except:
        raise
        db.rollback()


    # disconnect from server
        db.close()
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? give us a clue...

Comment: @Stuart Added more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
    sql = """INSERT INTO %s (name, age, gender)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""" % (test, "%s", "%s", "%s")
```

You need to separate Python's string substitution from MySQL's parameter substitution.  The above is a crude approach, but minimally different from your own code.

Comment: I seem to get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple' when i try it

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQLdb lets you use parameters for table names -- usually this is used for actual parameters (ones that are sometimes from user input and need sanitization - the name/age/gender part gets this right). You could use Python's string formats to achieve this:

```
sql = ("""INSERT INTO {table} (name, age, gender)
          VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""".format(table=table), (test))
```

Comment: Could you explain what the .format(table=table) does? Because when I tried this I got NameError: global name 'table' is not defined

Comment: Substitute the `table` variable for your table's name. [more info on this mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter)

Comment: I seem to get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple' when i try it